# Popping stack doesn't work right? (Stack from two queues)

Tags: c

I've been stewing over this one for a while, and I can't quite seem to figure out why at execution, when once the following function executes, and the test code in main calls to see if the stack is empty, for some reason it isn't. I can't seem to figure out the exact cause, though I have a feeling it has something to do with the "remove" function not deleting the last node, but for some reason, I can't figure out how to fix it.

```c
TYPE listStackPop (struct Stack* stack)
{
    /* FIXME: You will write this function */
    assert (stack != NULL);
    assert (!listQueueIsEmpty (stack->q1));
    return listQueueRemoveFront (stack->q1);
}

---later calls to listQueueRemoveFront---

TYPE listQueueRemoveFront (struct Queue* queue)
{
    /* FIXME: You will write this function */
    assert (queue != 0);
    assert (!listQueueIsEmpty (queue));
    struct Link* toDelete;
    toDelete = queue->head->next;
    if (toDelete == queue->tail) {
        queue->tail = queue->head;
    }
    else {
        queue->head->next = toDelete->next;
    }
    int retVal = toDelete->value;
    return retVal;
}

--For clarity, TYPE is defined as int--
```

I've tried going from simply `return toDelete->value` to copying toDelete's value to an int, and passing that int to be returned, as I thought maybe toDelete was being removed prematurely or something, but that isn't the case.
Unfortunately, google doesn't really have much info on this either. So far anyway.

Here is the full code on pastebin, in case anyone is interested to read it in full: https://pastebin.com/cDvdHmTu

I had expected it to pass, but for some reason, it failed even though all the other test cases passed.

results:

```
-------------------------------------------------
---- Testing stack from queue implementation ----
-------------------------------------------------
stack init...
stackIsEmpty == 1:      PASSED

pushing 4, 5, -300...
stackIsEmpty == 0:      PASSED

popping; val == -300:   PASSED
popping; val == 5:      PASSED
top val == 4    :       PASSED
popping; val == 4:      PASSED
stackIsEmpty == 1:      FAILED

pushing 0-9...
top val == 9    :       PASSED

C:\Users\Zedri\source\repos\Stack From Queues\Debug\Stack From Queues.exe (process 8928) exited with code 0.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

Compiler/IDE Used: Visual Studio 2019

-~-~-~Edit 1~-~-~-

removed malloc call to the toDelete pointer

~-~-~-Edit 2-~-~-~

Fixed code on pastebin. Issue resolved.

Comment: `toDelete = queue->head->next;` immediately overwrites the pointer to memory which was allocated by `malloc` in the line above. So when you later `free(toDelete)` this wasn't the pointer returned by `malloc` earlier.

Comment: [don't cast malloc()](https://medium.com/@ryanhaining/how-to-malloc-the-right-way-c-476375d53745)

Comment: malloc removed, still last test case fails :/
tried also on https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler since that is a Unix based online compiler, but it also failed. Good to know about that pointer though!

Comment: Also, thanks for the malloc article, I'll look into it

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I simply needed to move `queue->head->next = toDelete->next;` outside of the else block, and remove the else block entirely.